# How to show a dialog in javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, spring-mvc

I need to through alert message like "Are you want to navigate?" when user will modify some data but did not save that and trying to navigate to the other tab.

I want yes or No functionality on clicking on other tab. Not leave this page or stay on this.

Kinldy help me. Thanks In advanced.

```js
function goodbye(e) {
  if (!e) e = window.event;
  //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?'; //This is displayed on the dialog

  //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
window.onbeforeunload = goodbye;
```

I have used this but it is not showing yes/no.and in same page some buttons are there.  After clicking this page is refreshing and this message is coming.  can some one plz help me.

Comment: read the docs for the [beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `beforeunload` event.
Your handler should return a string, which will be displayed to a user.

The simplest usage example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Do you want to navigate away?";
};
```

If you have any other questions, refer to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display some info, then window.alert(Info) could be useful. Since you need to take opinion from user, you can use window.confirm(your Question)

Answer (score 0):

```
confirm("Do you want to leave this page?");
```

Confirm is similar to an alert box that popups up.But it has a difference,it gives the user two options: 'Ok' and 'cancel'.
If the user clicks 'ok' button,the window will unload and the user will navigate from the page successfully.
Confirm is often used for verfication and confirmation as the name suggests.

Comment: Yes I can do it.but problem is if user will click on any tab it message should comeThis thing will work if user click on for a particular tab or link or button.Am I right?

Comment: You have to asscociate it with an event handler!!...Like in form submission...if you have `onsubmit="retrun check()"`....Inside check...put a confirm box saying.."Do you want to submit?"...It the user clicks OK...value returned is true and the form will be submitted..It works in this manner.But you don't have to use an eventhandler in compulsion.If you want to associate it with user action..use eventhandlers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 <html>
   <body>
     <p>Click the button to demonstrate line-breaks in an alert box.</p>
     <button onclick="myFunction()">click it</button>
     <script>
         function myFunction() {
         alert("Do you want to navigate away ?");
         }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```